# Taking into account \r\n

Tags: c++, newline

I am trying to solve a problem on spoj. Apparently the input lines end with `\r\n` as per the comments. What I know about `\r\n` from previous questions is that its a windows thing. What I want to know is how to take it into account. Currently i am using `getline(cin,str)` in c++. What do I do to take into account the `\r\n.`

Comment: How would you like to "take them into account"?

Comment: @mbratch   as in how to get rid of it and store the line in a string object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `std::getline(std::cin, str)` the `'\n'` is already taken care of: `std::getline()` will read characters until it finds a `'\n'` and inserts these into `str`. It doesn't insert the `'\n'`, however.

Thus, you may be stuck with a a `'\r'` at the end of the string. If you are on Windows you can just open your file in text mode and the stream will extract them, too. If that's not the way to go, you can just determine if your `str` ends with a `'\r'` and remove it:

```
if (!str.empty() && str[str.size() - 1] == '\r') {
    str.erase(str.end() - 1);
}
```

If you want to remove all carriage returns (there may, in theory, some embedded in the string), you can use

```
str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), '\r'), str.end());
```

Finally, if you don't want to ever encounter the carriage returns, you can create a filtering stream buffer which just removes all `'\r'` (or just those from a `"\r\n"` sequence). Below is a quick example how a simple filtering stream buffer can be implemented:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <streambuf>
#include <string>

class crfilter
    : std::streambuf
{
    std::istream*   stream;
    std::streambuf* sbuf;
    char buffer[8];
    int underflow() {
        std::streamsize n;
        while (this->gptr() == this->egptr()
            && (n = this->sbuf->sgetn(buffer, 8))) {
            char* end = std::remove(buffer, buffer + n, '\r');
            this->setg(buffer, buffer, end);
        }
        return this->gptr() == this->egptr()
            ? std::char_traits<char>::eof()
            : std::char_traits<char>::to_int_type(*this->gptr());
    }
public:
    crfilter(std::istream& in): stream(&in), sbuf(in.rdbuf(this)) {}
    ~crfilter() { stream->rdbuf(this->sbuf); }
};

int main()
{
    crfilter filter(std::cin);
    std::string str;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, str)) {
        std::cout << "str='" << str << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They are carriage return/line feeds telling you the end of the line and beginning of the next.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP already knows that. I think his question has more to do with how to strip them out / add them back in while reading / writing the file.